# Trouble Saving with CoreData and Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, core-data, storage, swift2, xcode7-beta5

### Problem

I'm trying to simply save a record and then fetch it but I think I'm doing something wrong here as my record isn't saving. The output window just shows an empty array.

I'm using the **boiler-plate** AppDelegate CoreData stack in Xcode 7 beta 5. [[See Gist Here]](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/884a9e4a48ceddac43da)

### Attempt

**Entity**

[image]

**Model**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

// @func(Person) edit: removed 
class Person: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged var lastName: String?
}
```

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        seedPerson()
        fetch()
    }

    func seedPerson() {

        let managedContext = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        // add our data
        person.setValue("Dan", forKey: "firstName")
        person.setValue("Beaulieu", forKey: "lastName")

        // save it
        do {

            try AppDelegate().managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func fetch() {
        let moc = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext
        let personFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

        do {
            let fetchedPerson = try moc.executeFetchRequest(personFetch) as! [Person]
            print(fetchedPerson.first!.firstName)


        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch person: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

### Desired Behavior

What I'm trying to return is my first name from the data store, however I don't think my record is ever saved which is why I'm getting is an empty array.

**So my specific question is, how do I save using the boiler plate core data stack?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I was creating a new instance of managedObjectContext and trying to save to it which obviously wouldn't work because I was working with the managed context that I created at the top of my method.

```
func seedPerson() {

        let managedContext = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext

        //let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        //let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        let person = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        // add our data
        person.setValue("Dan", forKey: "firstName")
        person.setValue("Beaulieu", forKey: "lastName")

        // save it
        do {
            // this was the problem ///////////////
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

---

### Video

I've uploaded a video tutorial on how to setup core data in swift 2 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcQkBYu86h8